# How do I access the object that's been instantiated from the abstract class's subclass in java?

Tags: java, class, instance, abstract-class, subclass

I would like to be able to access the object that's been instantiated from the abstract class's subclass. Here's an example.

```
// A.java
public abstract class A {
  public int getNewNo() {
    int newNo = <Instance of B in this example here>.getNo() + 2;
    return newNo;
  }
}

// B.java
public class B extends A {
  public int getNo() {
    return 2;
  }
}

// C.java
public class C {
  public C(A a) {
    System.out.println("The number is "+a.getNewNo());
  }
}

// example.java
public void main(String args[]) {
  B b = new B();
  C c = new C(b);
  // should now print out "The number is 4"
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public abstract class A {
    public int getNewNo() {
        int newNo = getNo() + 2;
        return newNo;
    }

    abstract int getNo();
}
```

Will do the job.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
// A.java
public abstract class A {
  public abstract int getNo();

  public int getNewNo() {
    int newNo = getNo() + 2;
    return newNo;
  }
}
```

Comment: You beat me in seconds :)

Comment: @Reddy And you got the checkmark. What a world, what a world :)